# Python: Copy several files with one column into one file with multi-column

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following question in Python 2.7:
I have 20 different txt-files, each with exactly one column of numbers. Now - as an output - I would like to have one file with all those columns together. How can I concatenate one-column files in Python ? I was thinking about using the fileinput module, but I fear, I have to open all my different txt files at once ?
My idea:

```
filenames = ['input1.txt','input2.txt',...,'input20.txt']
import fileinput

with open('/path/output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in fileinput.input(filenames)
        write(line)
```

Any suggestions on that ?
Thanks for any help !

Comment: I would read the files sequentially, saving the columns in lists of lists. From there, it shoudl be reasonably straightforward to output the columns next to eachother.

Comment: Btw, how exactly do you mean "all those columns together"? Next to each other as a table, or just one after the other?

Comment: You can not append files together as columns. all you can do is to read every single file and then print them together as different columns.

Comment: Ok. Note that if you happen to be on some form on Unix, this is really easier done with `paste file1 file2 file3`.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. @Evert: Yes, I want them next to each other as a table.

Answer (score 0):

A very simply (naive?) solution is

```
filenames = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'd.txt']
columns = []
for filename in filenames:
    lines = []
    for line in open(filename):
        lines.append(line.strip('\n'))
    columns.append(lines)
rows = zip(*columns)
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in rows:
        outfile.write("\t".join(row))
        outfile.write("\n")
```

But on *nix (including OS X terminal and Cygwin), it's easier to

```
$ paste a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
```

from the command line.

Comment: @user707650 thanks for this answer, i have a question please, how to put the file name as column name above of the column ?  For Example: `input1` item1,item2 and so on?It does not work like this for example:`lines.insert(0,str(filename)) lines.append(line.strip('\n'))`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: a little functional approach. Using list comprehension to [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the file being read, to the accumulated columns, and then [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them to be a string again, one column (file) at a time:

```
filenames = ['input1.txt','input2.txt','input20.txt']
outputfile = 'output.txt'
#maybe you need to separate each column:
separator = " "
separator_list = []
output_list = []
for f in filenames:
    with open(f,'r') as inputfile:
        if len(output_list) == 0:
            output_list = inputfile.readlines()
            separator_list = [ separator for x in range(0, len(outputlist))]
        else:
            input_list = inputfile.readlines()
            output_list = [ ''.join(x) for x in [list(y) for y in zip(output_list, separator_list, input_list)]
with open(outputfile,'w') as output:
    output.writelines(output_list)
```

It will keep in memory the accumulator for the result (`output_list`), and one file at a time (the one being read, which is also the only file open for reading), but may be a little slower, and, of course, it is not fail-proof.